# Report Builder - merge not available

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I've created a matrix with row and column groups:

[image]

I've started to add a column that will hold data associated with the row groups:

[image]

This has left a gap between the column group labels and the column group data. When I go to merge the cells to bring the column group labels back next to the column group data, the merge option is not available:

[image]

I take it this is probably by design... but why? I don't see the problem with doing this.

Comment: It might be that your additional column is inside you column group. Try right-clicking any of the the cells that are not in the column group(Week commencing for example) and then do Insert/column/right

Comment: You should be able to delete the entire column. Merge is not available across group boundaries.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up rebuilding it as a table with row/column groups and was able to get it it to merge the text boxes the way I wanted. Perhaps I had somehow created the row groups on the wrong side of the column group boundaries.